# Dispatch Group Errors

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

So I am trying to restructure my API calls to make use of dispatchGroups so I don't have to make collectionViews and other elements reload so quick. I know that with dispatch groups you typically have to create one, enter, and then leave a certain number of times. Upon completion of this, you typically notify the main queue to do some operation. However, in the code snippet below it notifies the main queue before I even enter the dispatch group once. Which is throwing things way off. If anyone could look at my code and tell me what's going wrong I would really appreciate that.

```
 static func showFeaturedEvent(for currentLocation: CLLocation,completion: @escaping ([Event]) -> Void) {
        //getting firebase root directory
        let dispatchGroup1 = DispatchGroup()
        var currentEvents:[Event]?
        var geoFireRef: DatabaseReference?
        var geoFire:GeoFire?
        geoFireRef = Database.database().reference().child("featuredeventsbylocation")
        geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geoFireRef!)
        let circleQuery = geoFire?.query(at: currentLocation, withRadius: 17.0)
        circleQuery?.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in
            print("Key '\(key)' entered the search area and is at location '\(location)'")
            dispatchGroup1.enter()
            print("entered dispatch group")
            EventService.show(forEventKey: key, completion: { (event) in
                if let newEvent = event {
                    currentEvents?.append(newEvent)
                    dispatchGroup1.leave()
                    print("left dispatch group")
                }
            })

        })
        dispatchGroup1.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
            if let currentEventsFinal = currentEvents{
                completion(currentEventsFinal)
            }
        })
    }
```

I am running dispatch groups in other places. Im not sure if that would affect anything but I just felt like it was important to note in this question.

Comment: You need to `enter` before you start the asynchronous task and `leave` in the completion of the asynchronous task. You aren't executing the first `enter` until the first asynchronous task completes, so when execution hits your `notify` the dispatch group is empty and it fires straight away

Comment: hmmmm where would I put it though

Comment: I read the documentation and it says that if it is empty the group will be executed immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `enter` the group before you start the asynchronous task and `leave` in the completion of the asynchronous task. You aren't executing the first `enter` until the first asynchronous task completes, so when execution hits your `notify` the dispatch group is empty and it fires straight away.

It is also important that you call `leave` the same number of times that you call `enter` or the group will never empty, so be wary of calling `leave` inside conditional statements.

```
static func showFeaturedEvent(for currentLocation: CLLocation,completion: @escaping ([Event]) -> Void) {
    //getting firebase root directory
    let dispatchGroup1 = DispatchGroup()
    var currentEvents:[Event]?
    var geoFireRef: DatabaseReference?
    var geoFire:GeoFire?
    geoFireRef = Database.database().reference().child("featuredeventsbylocation")
    geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geoFireRef!)
    let circleQuery = geoFire?.query(at: currentLocation, withRadius: 17.0)

    disatchGroup1.enter()

    circleQuery?.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in
        print("Key '\(key)' entered the search area and is at location '\(location)'")

        dispatchGroup1.enter()

        EventService.show(forEventKey: key, completion: { (event) in
            if let newEvent = event {
                currentEvents?.append(newEvent)
                print("left dispatch group")
            }

            dispatchGroup1.leave()

        })

        dispatchGroup1.leave()

    })

    dispatchGroup1.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
        if let currentEventsFinal = currentEvents{
            completion(currentEventsFinal)
        }
    })
}
```